# WPF Data Binding Architecture Question

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, datacontext

I'm trying to learn how to use WPF binding and the MVVM architecture.  I'm running into some trouble with Dependency Properties.  I've tried to control the visibility of an item on the view by binding it to a DependencyProperty in the DataContext, but it doesn't work.  No matter what I set the `GridVisible` value to in the constructor of the view model below, it is always displayed as visible when I run the code.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**C# code** (ViewModel):

```
public class MyViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public MyViewModel ()
    {
        GridVisible = false;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridVisibleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "GridVisible",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyViewModel),
        new PropertyMetadata(false,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(GridVisibleChangedCallback)));

    public bool GridVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(GridVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GridVisibleProperty, value); }
    }

    protected static void GridVisibleChangedCallback(
        DependencyObject source,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do other stuff in response to the data change.
    }
}
```

**XAML code** (View):

```
<UserControl ... >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel x:Name="myViewModel" />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid x:Name="_myGrid"
        Visibility="{Binding Path=GridVisible,
            ElementName=myViewModel,
            Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}">

        <!-- Other elements in here -->

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

I've looked at several tutorials online, and it seems like I'm correctly following what I've found there.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the ElementName off your binding, that doesn't seem correct.
Change it to:

```
<Grid x:Name="_myGrid"
        Visibility="{Binding Path=GridVisible,
            Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}">
```

Comment: Actually I copied your code out and found it worked with the binding with and without the ElementName included.  What are you using the usercontrol on (ie a window or other usercontrol)?  Perhaps there is something wrong there (code you didn't include).

Comment: I removed ElementName and it still does not work.  It looks like you're right though--it probably has something to do with another part of my code, and not the sanitized version posted above.  Unfortunately I can't post the actual code since it's for work.

Comment: In that case, when you're running  your app and have the window open that contains this usercontrol, look in your Output window in VisualStudio for any errors with text similar to this 
"BindingExpression path error: 'GridVisible' property not found on 'object......"
the content of that message might help you debug into it further.
sorry I can't help you out more. good luck.

Comment: You were right, it was a typo!  I checked the Output window when running in Debug mode, and found that I had misspelled one of my data bindings.  It works perfectly now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged rather than inheriting from DependencyObject.
Implement the interface and raise PropertyChanged from your setter for the property.

```
    private bool gridVisible;

    public bool GridVisible
    {
        get { return gridVisible; }
        set 
        { 
            gridVisible = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("GridVisible"); 
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to reference your VM in your XAML with ElementName, nor do you need to name your VM.  When you assign it to the usercontrol.DataContext it becomes the default binding source for all children of the user control.

Answer (score 0):

The point of setting the ViewModel as DataContext is to enable easy relative bindings, all bindings where you only specify the `Path` take the DataContext as source which is inherited throughout the UserControl (unless it is set otherwise, for example in the templated items of an ItemsControl)

So once the DataContext is set on the UserControl you normally do not specify any source when binding to the VM. (Sources are `ElementName`, `RelativeSource` and `Source`)

Further i personally would not make ViewModels inherit from `DependencyObject` since this introduces thread-affinity, also the point of DependencyProperties is making sparse data structures more efficient by not creating unnecessary fields in all of them (ViewModels normally are quite the opposite of sparse).

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is the alternative to `DependencyObject` - most viewmodels use this instead of dependency properties.